# Where do I find my Subscribers in Bigcommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

A couple of people have subscribed to the newsletter and I cant find them anywhere.

Please help me to find my subscribers in bigcommerce.

Comment: https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Collecting-Newsletter-Subscriptions

Answer (score 2):

You would find them in Email Marketing -> Export only.